# Remove Duplicate Row Sql-Server

Tags: sql-server

i want to Remove One Row of date 2020-01-08 ..second row.. in SQL Server

[image: Sql Result-Click here]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
DECLARE @DataSource TABLE
(
    [StuffID] INT
   ,[PucnhOut] DATETIME2
)

INSERT INTO @DataSource ([StuffID], [PucnhOut])
VALUES (1, '2019-01-01 00:00:05')
      ,(1, '2019-01-01 00:00:06')
      ,(2, '2019-01-01 00:00:06');

WITH DataSource AS
(
    SELECT *
          ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY [StuffID] ORDER BY [PucnhOut] DESC) AS [Rank]
    FROM @DataSource
)
DELETE FROM DataSource
WHERE [Rank] > 1;

SELECT *
FROM @DataSource
```

The idea is to ranked the rows and delete those with rank bigger then `1`. We are using `ROW_NUMBER` - in the `partition by` clause list all column by which you are grouping.